# How can I get a menu bar on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

When I open Internet Explorer 9 on my desktop, across the top of the page (on the left hand side) are the words/categories File, Edit, View, Favorites, Tools, and Help, with the drop down menus under each of these allowing me to perform certain kinds of actions.

Is the same thing available on Google Chrome, and if so, how do I access/set this up?

Comment: Chrome currently does not offer such as a menu bar. You can look for other actions under the three horizontal bars sign.

Answer (score 1):

All of what you are looking for can be found at the three horizontal bars in the right hand corner. There are obviously a lot of different options that are listed under `File, Edit, View...etc`in IE, so it would be lengthy to explain how to do each one. Probably one that you would be most interested in is setting up your favorites bar.

To do this, click the three horizontal bars, go to settings, then check the box that says `always show the bookmarks bar` If you want to know how to do other things feel free to make another question, or edit this one.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For Chrome Version 57.0.2987.98 simply go to top left and see red, yellow, and green lollypops. Click the green to retrieve the menu bar and click again to disappear.